# HTML/CSS Center DIV inside DIV, absolute/relative problems

Tags: css, html, position, center

I've been searching for hours now, but can't seem to figure it out.

I want to center the Menu at the bottom of the Header Div, but it seems like it will either center it but keep it at the top or keep it at the bottom but not center it.

It has something to do with the position:relative/absolute, I believe.

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Transport2000</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />

    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />

    <meta name="description" content="Transport, mobilier, moloz etc." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="transport, chican, marfa, duba, bucuresti, romania, transport bucuresti, " />

    <meta name="author" content="Iulian" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/master3.css";</style>  
    <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/master3.css";</style>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
    <!--<h1><img src="images/header/banner.png" alt="Transport2000" /></h1>-->
        <div id="menu">
            <dt id="acasa">
<a href="index.htm">Acasa</a></dt>
            <dt id="galerie">
<a href="galerie.htm">Galerie</a></dt>
            <dt id="contact">
<a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></dt>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="container">


    <!--<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><br>
</ul>
    </div>-->


    <div id="content">
        <div class="padding">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
        adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies 
        scelerisque erat eu mattis. Duis lacinia, 
        ante non adipiscing euismod, dui lorem 
        adipiscing turpis, et convallis leo orci 
        ac ligula. Proin porta risus id tortor aliquet 
        sollicitudin. Sed suscipit blandit nisi, ac 
        laoreet nulla ultrices sed. Curabitur velit 
        enim, eleifend nec faucibus vitae, imperdiet 
        eget lectus. Suspendisse quis ligula urna. 
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
        parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
        Quisque hendrerit nisl eu nibh facilisis in 
        rutrum elit tempor. Praesent vel nisi quis 
        justo sodales elementum.</p>
        <p>Fusce felis dui, pharetra vel condimentum 
        sed, elementum non nisl. Maecenas condimentum 
        pretium augue, non rhoncus magna hendrerit at. 
        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci 
        luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam 
        euismod laoreet sollicitudin. Lorem ipsum dolor 
        sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor 
        adipiscing nibh, a dignissim nunc rutrum in. Donec 
        ut nulla neque. Aenean mi sapien, pulvinar a 
        interdum in, fringilla pharetra turpis. Aliquam 
        aliquet volutpat imperdiet. Integer eu magna purus, 
        id mattis tortor. Suspendisse porttitor ligula 
        vitae erat pellentesque auctor. Vivamus non 
        interdum urna. Duis fermentum venenatis turpis, 
        at vestibulum mauris ultricies vel. Aliquam in 
        arcu in orci rutrum condimentum vel at ipsum. 
        Pellentesque scelerisque eleifend ipsum, at 
        scelerisque eros condimentum eu. Phasellus 
        ante metus, fermentum id lobortis id, rutrum 
        id magna.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
        adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies 
        scelerisque erat eu mattis. Duis lacinia, 
        ante non adipiscing euismod, dui lorem 
        adipiscing turpis, et convallis leo orci 
        ac ligula. Proin porta risus id tortor aliquet 
        sollicitudin. Sed suscipit blandit nisi, ac 
        laoreet nulla ultrices sed. Curabitur velit 
        enim, eleifend nec faucibus vitae, imperdiet 
        eget lectus. Suspendisse quis ligula urna. 
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
        parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
        Quisque hendrerit nisl eu nibh facilisis in 
        rutrum elit tempor. Praesent vel nisi quis 
        justo sodales elementum.</p>

        </div>

</div>



</div>
    <div id="footer">

        <div id="copyright">
            Copyright &#169; 2013 Blahzx Designs<br />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background-image:url('bg.png');
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#content h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#content p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height:141px;
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('top.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#header-content { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }

/* Menu */

#menu {     height: 30px; 
    width: 639px; 
    margin-left: auto !important;  
    margin-right: auto !important;  
    text-align: center;  
    position: absolute;  
    bottom: 0; }

#menu dl { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
/* IE5 Mac Hack \*/ 
#menu { padding-left: 0; } 
/*/ 
#menu { padding-left: 100px; overflow: visible; } 
/* End Hack */

#menu dt { float: left; }

#menu dt a {
    display: block;
    height: 0px !important;
    height /**/:44px; /* IE 5/Win hack */ 
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#menu dt a:hover {

}
#menu dt#acasa,
#menu dt#acasa a {width: 182px; background-image: url(../images/menu/acasa.png); }
#menu dt#acasa a:hover {width: 182px; background-image: url(../images/menu/acasa_on.png); }

#menu dt#galerie,
#menu dt#galerie a { width: 221px; background-image: url(../images/menu/galerie.png); }
#menu dt#galerie a:hover {width: 221px; background-image: url(../images/menu/galerie_on.png); }

#menu dt#contact,
#menu dt#contact a { width: 236px; background-image: url(../images/menu/contact.png); }
#menu dt#contact a:hover {width: 236px; background-image: url(../images/menu/contact_on.png); }

#content {
    width:960px;
    margin-right:280px;
    line-height:18px;
}

#content a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:hover {
    color: #CC00FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content .padding {
    padding: 25px;
}

#footer {
    width:auto;
    height:137px;
    clear: both;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    text-align: center;
    background-image:url('bot.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#footer a {
    color: #c9c9c9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #ffd800;
}

#footer #altnav {
    clear: both;
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 13px;
}

#footer #copyright {
    padding-top: 110px;
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I have added the WHOLE code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#menu {     
    height: 30px; 
    width: 639px;  
    text-align: center;  
    position: absolute;  
    bottom: 0; 
    left:50%; 
    margin:0 0 0 -320px; /* left 50% PLUS margin top 0 right 0 bottom 0 left (halfwidth) makes sure it fits different screen*/
    }
```

Try set margins left and right both to be "auto" to center it, rather than margin: 0 auto; <- which sets it to the left hand side.

Since you may have it somewhere else conflicts with those ones, to contains an "!important" declaration, it will override the corresponding declaration in the prior or later style sheet.

Comment: Still won't get centered. There must be a conflict somewhere.. It's impossible that none of the answers I have tried work.

Comment: Since you may have it somewhere else conflicts with those ones, to contains an "!important" declaration to those 2 margin lines, it will override the corresponding declaration in the prior or later style sheet.

Comment: Still won't center. I can center it without the position elements, but then it won't be at the bottom of the div..

I have added the entire code for better view.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want `:`

http://jsfiddle.net/CMVbX/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <!--<h1><img src="images/header/banner.png" alt="Transport2000" /></h1>-->
        <div id="menu">
            <dt id="acasa">
<a href="index.htm">Acasa</a></dt>
            <dt id="galerie">
<a href="galerie.htm">Galerie</a></dt>
            <dt id="contact">
<a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></dt>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Css:**

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    height:141px;
    background-color:blue;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/*#header-content { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }*/

/* Menu */

#menu { background-color:red; width:100%; height: 30px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
#menu dl { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
/* IE5 Mac Hack \*/ 
#menu { padding-left: 0; } 
/*/ 
#menu { padding-left: 100px; overflow: visible; } 
/* End Hack */

#menu dt { float: left; }

#menu dt a {
    display: block;
    height: 0px !important;
    height /**/:44px; /* IE 5/Win hack */ 
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#menu dt a:hover {

}
#menu dt#acasa,
#menu dt#acasa a {width: 182px; background-image: url(../images/menu/acasa.png); }
#menu dt#acasa a:hover {width: 182px; background-image: url(../images/menu/acasa_on.png); }

#menu dt#galerie,
#menu dt#galerie a { width: 221px; background-image: url(../images/menu/galerie.png); }
#menu dt#galerie a:hover {width: 221px; background-image: url(../images/menu/galerie_on.png); }

#menu dt#contact,
#menu dt#contact a { width: 236px; background-image: url(../images/menu/contact.png); }
#menu dt#contact a:hover {width: 236px; background-image: url(../images/menu/contact_on.png); }
```

Comment: Still not centered. :(

Comment: Please add your code to the answer body, link only answers tend to get deleted

Answer (score 0):

You should have to declare the position you just need to set the width of the menu div and set its margins to auto i.e.:

```
#menu
{
width:80%;
margin-left:auto !important;
margin-right:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? If i just replace my part with this or just implement it. It still won't center it. There must be a conflict somewhere..

Comment: I have edited it to state the margin more explicity and used the !important qualifier to override any conflicts. It's important that you remove the position attribute as well. I have tested this and it works.

Comment: I did this and it centered it, but now I'm back to the point where I need to also bring the menu at the bottom of the Header-Div. Because right now it's at the top.

#header {
 width: 100%;
 height:141px;
 background-image:url('top.png');
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}



/* Menu */

#menu { height: 30px; width: 639px;
margin-left:auto !important;
margin-right:auto !important;}